# showing progress of a task while a button is executing in java

Tags: java, netbeans, jprogressbar

I am executing several SQL queries in the function evoked by a button in java. I wish to show the status of the same, and I am using a jProgressBar for the same. But the problem is it will only update after the button has finished executing itself, making it pointless to show the progress. How can I display the actual progress of the executing button.

Comment: check into threadworkers, it sounds like your program only has one thread running right now. Also, some code would be great!

Comment: yes.. i realized i had been missing n threads on which i had no idea.. read about them and successfully implemented the same through SwingWorker..

Comment: excellent! glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Make a thread dispatcher like this

```
public class ThreadDispatcher implements Runnable { 

public ThreadDispatcher() {

}

public void run() {

        //call the method related to query here        

    }           


}
```

When button pressed call this class and let this class evoke your query related function.

It may be like this when you press the button.

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadDispatcher());
 thread.start();
 sleep(100);
```

catch the `InterruptedException ex`.

[Link for Thread example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html)

Comment: i read about multithreading and came across java SwingWorker.. that worked thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the computation on a background thread, not the main thread.

Take a look at the [Java SwingWorker Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).